# Vim color scheme not being applied

Tags: vim, colors, vimrc

I'm trying to use this color scheme:

https://github.com/Konstruktionist/vim/blob/master/colors/Kafka.vim

Here is my `~/.vim/colors`:

```
xxx@xxx:~/.vim/colors$ ls -l
total 16
-rw-rw-r-- 1 xxx xxx 15245 Feb 11 17:04 Kafka.vim
```

Here is my `/usr/share/vim/vimrc`:

```
" All system-wide defaults are set in $VIMRUNTIME/debian.vim and sourced by
" the call to :runtime you can find below.  If you wish to change any of those
" settings, you should do it in this file (/etc/vim/vimrc), since debian.vim
" will be overwritten everytime an upgrade of the vim packages is performed.
" It is recommended to make changes after sourcing debian.vim since it alters
" the value of the 'compatible' option.

" This line should not be removed as it ensures that various options are
" properly set to work with the Vim-related packages available in Debian.
runtime! debian.vim

" Color scheme
colorscheme Kafka

" Uncomment the next line to make Vim more Vi-compatible
" NOTE: debian.vim sets 'nocompatible'.  Setting 'compatible' changes numerous
" options, so any other options should be set AFTER setting 'compatible'.
"set compatible

" Vim5 and later versions support syntax highlighting. Uncommenting the next
" line enables syntax highlighting by default.
if has("syntax")
  syntax on
endif

" If using a dark background within the editing area and syntax highlighting
" turn on this option as well
"set background=dark

" Uncomment the following to have Vim jump to the last position when
" reopening a file
"if has("autocmd")
"  au BufReadPost * if line("'\"") > 1 && line("'\"") <= line("$") | exe "normal! g'\"" | endif
"endif

" Uncomment the following to have Vim load indentation rules and plugins
" according to the detected filetype.
if has("autocmd")
  filetype plugin indent on
endif

" The following are commented out as they cause vim to behave a lot
" differently from regular Vi. They are highly recommended though.
"set showcmd        " Show (partial) command in status line.
"set showmatch      " Show matching brackets.
"set ignorecase     " Do case insensitive matching
"set smartcase      " Do smart case matching
"set incsearch      " Incremental search
"set autowrite      " Automatically save before commands like :next and :make
"set hidden     " Hide buffers when they are abandoned
"set mouse=a        " Enable mouse usage (all modes)

" Source a global configuration file if available
if filereadable("/etc/vim/vimrc.local")
  source /etc/vim/vimrc.local
endif
```

But the scheme doesn't take affect. When I open a file using `vim`, there is no highlighting at all. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have already try to `set t_Co=256`in your vimrc to enable 256-color mode?

But this also depends of your terminal capabilities. 
So if the settings in vimrc is not enough I suggest you have a look to the `TERM` variable of the terminal you are using:

`echo $TERM`to see what is the current setting.
The result should be:`xterm-256color` or `screen-256color`.

To define the TERM:
`export TERM=xterm-256color`